# How do I execute a command contained within a variable in PHP?

Tags: php, function

Currently, I'm passing a command into a user-defined function in PHP. How do I have PHP execute this when I ask it to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll want to either use [`eva`l](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php) or [`call_user_func`](http://nz.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php), depending on whether it's a set of expressions or simply a function call.

Answer (score 1):

If it's a shell command you want to execute you use [backticks](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.execution.php) or [shell_exec](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php).

Answer (score 1):

If its a method in a class, maybe this will be useful :

```
// The method to call
$proposed_method = 'some_method_name';

// See if its available
if (is_callable(array($this,$proposed_method), FALSE))
{
    // Call the method
    return $this->$proposed_method();
}
```

Where $this in the is_callable refers to the current class.

Answer (score 0):

As `eval()` would be able to arbitrarily execute code on your server, maybe you can generate class files from your user application with any functions that a user might be authorized to call, then check for existence of a function using introspection in the newly generated class file first.